# Why when I check to see if a string in a loop is included in an array of strings do I get false for all of them?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm trying to check if a state is included in an array of state strings, but for some reason it's always equating to false. Am I writing this right?

I've tried using underscore contains, but it does the same thing

```
T.get('followers/list', {screen_name: ''}, function(err, data, response){
  let states = [
  "AK",
  "AL",
  "AR",
  "AS",
  "AZ",
  "CA",
  "CO",
  "CT",
  "DC",
  "DE",
  "FL",
  "GA",
  "GU",
  "HI",
  "IA",
  "ID",
  "IL",
  "IN",
  "KS",
  "KY",
  "LA",
  "MA",
  "MD",
  "ME",
  "MI",
  "MN",
  "MO",
  "MS",
  "MT",
  "NC",
  "ND",
  "NE",
  "NH",
  "NJ",
  "NM",
  "NV",
  "NY",
  "OH",
  "OK",
  "OR",
  "PA",
  "PR",
  "RI",
  "SC",
  "SD",
  "TN",
  "TX",
  "UT",
  "VA",
  "VI",
  "VT",
  "WA",
  "WI",
  "WV",
  "WY"
]
  _.each(data, loc => {
    _.each(loc, data => {
      if(data.location){
        var statesyes = states.includes(JSON.stringify(data.location.split(', ').pop()));
        console.log(statesyes);
      };
    })
  })
})
```

For instance, I should be getting back true for some of these and false for others, which is the goal. But I'm only getting false.

```
false
"South Africa"
false
"South Africa"
false
"The dark part of the web"
false
"MI"
false
"FL"
false
"United States"
false
"WV"
false
"TX"
false
"Iowa"
false
"IA"
false
"MN"
false
"IA"
false
"Big Sky Country"
false
"USA"
false
"MO"
false
"IA"
false
```

I'm getting false for all of them.

Comment: Don't call `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: Without seeing what data is, it is not possible to diagnose.

Comment: @Barmar that fixed it, but is it not a string?

Comment: JSON.stringify is adding an extra set of quotes around the string.

Comment: @Barmar thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Invoking `JSON.stringify` on the value returned from `data.location.split(', ').pop()` means that you're comparing with quoted text.

`JSON.stringify("Hello")` -> `"\"Hello\""`

Remove the call to `JSON.stringify`